# What kind of geometric transformation (more general than a projective transform / homography) is this?

Tags: matrices, geometry, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry

I have an A4 (21 * 29.7 cm)  sheet of paper, that, when photographed with a phone camera, **looks like the quadrilateral $ABCD$**.
If we precisely know the coordinates of the **four points** A, B, C, D on the photo, and also the desired target coordinates of A', B', C', D' , we can do a [perspective/projective transform](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#getperspectivetransform) / homography / deskewing. It currently works (succesfully with Python with `opencv` library).

**Problem**: the position of E', F' (i.e. E, F transformed by the homography) is not exactly what it should be. Example: A'B' is 21 cm, A'C' is 29.7 cm, **but the length A'E' is 9.7 cm, whereas on the original sheet of paper, this length was 10 cm**. It is not bad, but I would like to improve the precision of this homography.

The real problem: an homography is **totally fixed** by 4 input points (A, B, C, D) and 4 target points (A', B', C', D'), so there is no degree of freedom left to choose between the result (1), (2) or (3) below (see the orange numbers on the graph).

**Question:** is there a more general transform than an homography allowing to have situation (1), (2), (3), or any other position of E', F'?  More precisely, is there a well-known kind of transform that can respect these conditions:

- A should be mapped to A',
- B to B',
- C to C',
- D to D',
- **E to E''**

?

(This seems to require 10 degrees of freedom?)

[image]

Note:

- The 3 or 4 millimeters error does not come from lack of precision of my measurement on the sheet of paper (I did it with ~ 0.5mm precision), it also does not come from the lack of precision of the measurement of the coordinates of A, B, C, D (i did it precisely and carefully, by zooming, etc.)
- I suspect it comes from camera lense distorsion:

  [image]

  but this is uncontrollable (it varies from a camera to another)

Comment: Interesting question. Can you see the distortion by photographing a grid?

Comment: @EThanBolker. Very good idea! I will do it tomorrow (nearly 3 am now :)), I probably have such grid paper at home! I'll post the photo. (Note: for my application, I will not be able to ask people to photograph a grid, so I need to find a solution that works for every kind of distorded lense ;))

Comment: Better try with more than one camera.

Comment: If you suspect that the error comes from lens distortion, I think you’d be better off trying to correct it properly instead of trying to kluge something together. Since you can see the edges of the paper in the image, it should be possible to test for curvature of those lines.

Comment: @amd I'm coding an app that any user with a phone camera (who doesn't even know about lense distorsion or about the fact there's a lense!) can use. Unfortunately, I can't ask them to do a camera calibration before using the app, it would make the user experience bad for most users. So I have to do the best I can to have the less distorsion possible without asking user for a calibration.

Comment: You can estimate the distortion function yourself by measuring the deviation of known lines in the image, such as the edges of the paper, from a linear map.

Comment: I know tools like [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) will do some kind of lens correction. Reading the docs might give you a clue as to the maths behind that. In particular, have a look at https://wiki.panotools.org/Barrel_distortion.